# Laravel blade iterating over php array/object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I'm having trouble outputting a list of key value pairs in Laravel blade.

My show.blade.php template is:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

  <ul>
    @foreach ($datapoint as $key => $value)

      <li>{{ $key, $value }}</li>

    @endforeach
  </ul>

  {{ $datapoint }}
@endsection
```

And my controller which displays this template is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Hyfes;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CaptainController extends Controller
{
    public function getLiveData ()
    {
      $datapoint = Hyfes::find(1);

      return view('captain.show')->with('datapoint', $datapoint);
    }
}
```

The data output to the view in the browser is this:

- incrementing
- exists
- wasRecentlyCreated
- timestamps

  {"date":"08/07/2017","time":"12:02:25","boat_name":"cyclone","current_location":"North Greenwich Pier","status":"docked","embarked":26,"disembarked":2,"people_on_board":24,"current_speed":0,"hotel_power":231,"battery_power_demand":342,"battery_output_power":23,"engine_output_power":12,"battery_power_stored":100,"battery_depth_of_discharge":323,"fuel_consumption_rate":7,"nox":432,"co2":213,"battery_state_of_charge":100,"id":1}

Ideally, I would like to see a list of bullet points showing e.g.:

- date: 8/07/2017
- time: 12:00:01
- boat_name: cyclone

Comment: maybe because find doesn't return an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `Hyfes::find(1)` will return an object of the type `App\Hyfes` and not an array. By looping over the key value pairs you are getting all properties. Laravel adds a lot of extra properties for keeping track of the object.

A better way to do this is using the Laravel [`getAttributes`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getAttributes) function. This will only get the attributes loaded from the database.
Like so:

```
@foreach ($datapoint->getAttributes() as $key => $value)
    <li>{{ $key }}: {{ $value }}</li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :) consider marking this as the answer to you question so other users might also find this.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to iterate over a non array variable in your template. You have to be explicit about the values of the objects you would like to see in your template.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

  <ul>
      <li>date: {{ $datapoint->date }}</li>
      <li>time: {{ $datapoint->time }}</li>
      <!-- and so on -->
  </ul>

@endsection
```